# Why isn't my event "myTimer_Elapsed updating the label on my device?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019, system.timers.timer

I am sorry if this has been asked.  I couldn't find the answer to this question specifically and am stuck.  I am learning about timers right now.  I am a VBA programmer and dabble in C#.

I am trying to write a cross-platform app right now and am having trouble with my myTimer.Elapsed event from updating the label as it is supposed to do.

I have read the timers chapter in C# Notes for Professionals from goalkicker.com and have tried to replicate their countdown timer.  I have also read the Microsoft API for Timer.Elapsed Event.  Neither have given me an explicit answer as to where I am going wrong.  Google hasn't been too kind, either, as I might be querying incorrectly.

I have tried stopping the timer, just allowing the method to run, writing to the label directly within my Elapsed method and updating the label in a separate method (as seen in the code).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Plugin.Geolocator;

namespace LocationServices
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public int timeLeft = 3;
        public Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        SensorSpeed speed = SensorSpeed.UI; //ignore

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cmdGetLocation.Clicked += GetLocation; //ignore
            cmdStartTimer.Clicked += StartTimer;
            Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += MainPage_ReadingChanged; //ignore

            InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void UpdateTimeLeftLabel(string NumberToDisplay)
        {
            txtTimeRemaining.Text = "Time left: " + NumberToDisplay;
        }

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            myTimer.Elapsed += MyTimer_Elapsed;
            UpdateTimeLeftLabel(timeLeft.ToString()); //working just fine
        }

        private void MyTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            UpdateTimeLeftLabel(timeLeft.ToString()); //this one is not working.

            if (timeLeft <= 0)
            {
                myTimer.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                timeLeft -= 1;
                myTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void StartTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

My timer event is firing as breakpoints are being hit as expected.  The timeLeft variable is being adjusted as has been verified in the immediate window.  It's just the label that is not getting updated.

Comment: OH!  I have also changed me StartTimer method to change the label directly without it actually calling the myTimer.Start() and that was successful in updating the label I was hoping to update.

Comment: So, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to force your UI code to run on the UI thread

```
private void UpdateTimeLeftLabel(string NumberToDisplay)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
          txtTimeRemaining.Text = "Time left: " + NumberToDisplay;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Jason, this worked.  I appreciate the solution.

Where did I go wrong, though?  Is it that I am not too versed on threading?  I understand the concept of threading and what multi-threading is, but I cannot seem to fully understand threading in use yet.

Comment: UI updates can only be done from the main UI thread.  The Timer you are using fires on a background thread.  BeginInvokeOnMainThread just forces your code to run on the UI thread so it can update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more information here as supporting information

.NET includes four classes named Timer, each of which offers different functionality:

- `System.Timers.Timer`, which fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Threading.Timer`, which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (.NET Framework only), a Windows Forms component that fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment; it executes on the UI thread.
- `System.Web.UI.Timer` (.NET Framework only), an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

Now your problem is that you are most likely using the Threading Timer. What that means is you need to Marshall back to the *UI thread*, as you cannot up date the *UI* from another thread.

See Jasons answer

Comment: So, it is about my lack of understanding of threading.  I will dig into that C# book about that tonight.  Thank you both!  :)